# ui-view fade in transition

Tags: html, angularjs, css

I have the following CSS markup to have a smooth fade-in transition on view changes in AngularJS:

```
[ui-view].ng-enter {
    transition: .7s;
    opacity: 0;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It works fine when using the navigation menu I've built, but when I land directly on the view (ie: `/#/products/1`) there is no fade in. Is there any other event I need to add code to ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you would post bit more relevant code, it might be easier to help. Probably how your  views are set up.

Comment: OK, what do you want to know ? I'd think the required CSS is independent of how the views are set up.

Comment: You could just have a function that runs right away and adds an animation class in the Directive controller of whatever view you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ui-view].ng-enter {
     opacity:0.7
    -webkit-transition:opacity 2s ; 
    -moz-transition:opacity 2s ; 
    -o-transition:opacity 2s ; 
    -ms-transition:opacity 2s ; 
    transition:opacity 2s;
}

[ui-view].ng-enter-active { opacity:1;}
```

Comment: did you read the question properly? you have just added the vendor prefixes.

Comment: Please add some useful information and/or description to your answer, describing why do you think this could be used to solve the problem in question

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like below:

```
/* Have to set height explicity on ui-view 
to prevent collapsing during animation*/

.animated-view.well{
 height: 65px; 
}

.ui-view-container {
  position: relative;
}


.ng-enter, .ng-leave {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

I have set up a simple demo app in **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Je62Lz333TumvZlUZFfH?p=preview)** with working animation.